# Selenium web driver : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I am clicking on image button, but getting error as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Html:

```
<img src="../RupeeWeb/images/entry/trade_jm.png" style="width: 25px; margin-bottom: -1px;"/>
```

My code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"1556776066373-0-uiGrid-002G-cell\"]/a[1]/img")).click();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Kindly update your question with proper HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be problem of Wait. Try the code to wait for that particular element.

```
WabDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"1556776066373-0-uiGrid-002G-cell\"]/a[1]/img")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"1556776066373-0-uiGrid-002G-cell\"]/a[1]/img")).click();
```